# CakePHP TIMESTAMPDIFF in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

In my controller in CakePHP I am attempting to get the difference between two dates.  Here is the regular query that I know works in traditional SQL.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, posts.post_date, answers.answer_date) AS 'timestampdiff' 
FROM answers 
INNER JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.id
INNER JOIN tags_questions ON questions.id = tags_questions.question_id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_questions.tag_id 
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = questions.posts_id WHERE tags.id = 1;
```

Now in CakePHP3.0 (that is the version I am using). I am attempting to build the same exact query (shown above) but using the query builder CakePHP has. I ended up constructing that query below:

```
$time_diffs = $this->Answers->find('all')
->join(['Questions' => [
     'table' => 'questions',
     'type' => 'INNER',
     'conditions' => array('Answers.question_id = Questions.id')
]])
->join(['TagsQuestions' => [
     'table' => 'tags_questions',
     'type' => 'INNER',
     'conditions' => array('TagsQuestions.question_id = Questions.id')
]])
->join(['Tags' => [
     'table' => 'tags',
     'type' => 'INNER',
     'conditions' => array('TagsQuestions.tag_id = Tags.id')
]])
->join(['Posts' => [
     'table' => 'posts',
     'type' => 'INNER',
     'conditions' => array('Questions.post_id = Posts.id')
]])
->select(['timestampdiff' => 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Posts.post_date, Answers.answer_date)'])
->where(['Tags.id' => 1])->toArray();
```

Now here is where the error comes into play. When I execute the CakePHP controller code, I get the this:

"Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SECOND, Posts.post_date, Answers.answer_date') AS 'timestampdiff' FROM 'answers' at line 1."

When I went to go check what sort of query CakePHP generated for me, I found a similar but slightly different query from the original one I wrote (first block of code).

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(`SECOND, posts.post_date, answers.answer_date`) AS 'timestampdiff' 
FROM answers 
INNER JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.id
INNER JOIN tags_questions ON questions.id = tags_questions.question_id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_questions.tag_id 
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = questions.posts_id WHERE tags.id = 1;
```

Now here is the part I do not understand, why did CakePHP generate those odd ` quotes symbols around my parameters for the TIMESTAMPDIFF in CakePHP? I know that if I remove them, the query will work just fine. I suppose my question is, given the error I'm getting? How can I modify the querybuild CakePHP code to not have those odd ` symbols near my parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if CakePHP would add single quotes around the alias. It seem that you're using MySQL, so I'd expect `timestamp` to be enclosed in backticks (default quote character).

Your SQL snippet has backticks added because you have auto-quoting enabled, and string values in select lists are expected to be identifiers, which are being quoted. Obviously this doesn't work well with that non-identifier.

If you want to use SQL snippets, then you need to pass them as expression objects instead of strings, like:

```php
->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    return [
        'timestampdiff' => $query->newExpr(
            'TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Posts.post_date, Answers.answer_date)'
        )
    ];
})
```

Or better yet build them using the functions builder, which produces transpilable, auto-autoquoting compatible expressions:

```php
[
    'timestampdiff' => $query->func()->TIMESTAMPDIFF([
        'SECOND' => 'literal',
        'Posts.post_date' => 'identifier',
        'Answers.answer_date' => 'identifier'
    ])
]
```

Btw., if you've setup associations properly, you could use two basic `innerJoinWith()` instead of all these manual joins:

```php
->innerJoinWith('Questions.Tags')
->innerJoinWith('Questions.Posts')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::innerJoinWith()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_innerJoinWith)**

Comment: Hey @ndm that was perfect! Just what I needed! Thanks so much for the feeback!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I've updated the question to use a callback for the `select()` method, that way you don't have to split up the query generation. @Matthew